# Counting all previous occurrences of a class in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/MAane/

When clicking any of the list items, I'm counting how many previous elements there are in said list, but what I need is to be able to count all li items in the DOM previous to the one I clicked (so if I clicked item number 2 in the second list, the alert would be =5)

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    var x=0;
    $(this).prevAll("li").each(function() {
       x++;
    });
    alert(x);
});
```

I could probably go through a loop of parent(), prev(), etc, but consider that these lists are dynamic - so I'm not really looking for a fix on this example per se, but something that can actually crawl up through any DOM.

Comment: Select all list items, get the index of `this` in that collection of list items, then select all list items from that list that have an index less than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `index()` for that, and check where in the collection of LI elements the currently clicked one is :

```
$("ul li").on('click', function(){
    var x = $("ul li").index(this);
    alert(x);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MAane/3/)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
$("ul").each(function () {
    $(this).find('li').each(function (i, e) {
        $(e).click(function () {
            alert(i);
        });
    });
});
```